# CSS and JS not loading with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I am using apache's mod_rewrite module to improve my URL structure(for one instance- `www.mydomainname.com/user.php?u=somename`) to some fancy URL like `www.mydomainname.com/user/somename` . I have successfully achieved it until I got into this very bad situation of CSS and JS relative path issue. 
Whenever I open up `www.mydomainname.com/user/somename`, it loads successfully without CSS and JS with only text and basic HTML. I used chrome's "inspect element" feature, which help me to know the following errors that occurred.

```
GET http://www.mydomainname.com/user/css/style.css 404 (Not Found) somename:5
GET http://www.mydomainname.com/user/css/developer.css 404 (Not Found) somename:6
GET http://www.mydomainname.com/user/js/jquery-1.5.2.js 404 (Not Found) somename:7
GET http://www.mydomainname.com/user/js/jquery.form.js 404 (Not Found) somename:5
```

The .htaccess file has following contents-

```
DirectoryIndex index.html.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule    ^user/([^/.]+)/?$    user.php?u=$1    [L]
```

The user.php is residing in the parent folder as well as the CSS and JS folders. I got to know the cause but do not know how to remove the errors.

**EDIT**: The path of CSS and JS given in the user.php file are-

```
<link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/style.css">
<link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/developer.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding absolute paths (just add `/` at the beginning of the URL):

```
<link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href = "/css/style.css">
<link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href = "/css/developer.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot man for pointing out my this little mistake. I have not looked up for this. But a basic thing is still left as problem. I now use ajax from user.php page to request user data from `userdetail.php`, userdetail.php lies in same directory the `user.php` lives in, but it is making POST request to the path `user/userdetail.php` instead of `userdetail.php`

Comment: @AshutoshChaudhary Well, you have to do the same thing as before...instead of posting to `userdetail.php` post to `/userdetail.php`.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
 DirectoryIndex index.html.php
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule    ^user/([^/.]+)/?$    user.php?u=$1    [L]
```

I believe you are allowing requests for file but not for directories.  The JS/CSS files are in sub directories.

// UPDATE
The relative paths your are using are the issue.

The code you have pasted for your paths, essentially says, Look for this css file in the sub folder of the **current folder**.  The subfolder does not exist, hence the error.

Change your code to the following.

```
<link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href = "/css/style.css">
<link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href = "/css/developer.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

This will translate to look for the files from the root folder.

Comment: tried but unfortunately got the same result as before. The issue is that the path of css given in user.php is relative. I am going to edit my question to let you know the paths, which are also being modified.

Comment: I see the update. Where are the files located physicaly? in a subfolder of user or root?

Comment: I am just looking out for if there is any way the output, which is coming on the `user/somename url`, to be loaded the same way it is being loaded with `user.php?u=somename`. Although, `user.php?u=somename` is working perfect with all CSS and JS being loaded, but why not with `/user/somename`?

Comment: user is not a directory, it's a PHP file. CSS and JS folders are inside the root directory where all the files( index.html.php, user.php) are residing.

Answer (score -2):

You dont need to worry about it. You can just open "httpd.conf" file from apache. and remove hash from below line.

Example:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Change it it:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Comment: I think that is already being considered as a command rather than commented out block. That's why it is even working. I just want to know that how can I modify my output in which the css files are being output as per url?

Comment: I found that in above comment you write that "css and js" folders are inside root dir. if so then you just need URL like below (Remove User from URL): 
http://www.mydomainname.com/css/style.css 404 (Not Found)