# htaccess and css files

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess, xampp

I have the this project:

[image]

In the index I check the url with this code:

```
if( isset( $_GET['url'] ) ) {
   if( file_exists( 'classes/layout/'.$_GET['url'].'.php' ) ) {
    require_once 'classes/layout/'.$_GET['url'].'.php';
   } 
}
```

And in my .htacces this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ index.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

This works great. When is go to example: 127.0.0.1/test/pages/edit the index includes edit.php but in the index i use a css file named: test.css wich make the whole html background red.

If i go to 127.0.0.1/test/ i see the whole background red. But when i go to 127.0.0.1/test/pages/edit it is white. I checked the urls of the css file and i get this:

127.0.0.1/test/ = 127.0.0.1/test/cache/css/test.css

127.0.0.1/test/pages/edit = 127.0.0.1/test/pages/cache/css/test.css

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305963/css-and-js-not-loading-with-mod-rewrite/13306329#13306329

Comment: Quick side-note: the code samples you posted create a potential security issue (path traversal). You should never trust user-input!

Comment: show us the line, on how are you including that test.css in your entry script.

Comment: To elaborate on Martijn's point: If you put that code on a publicly available web server you will open that server up to the whole world. You should instead compare the value of the URL parameter against a predefined set of values, and load the correct file based on that. For that to make sense the parameter should have a different name, say pageId, or something. Then do: `if($_GET['pageId'] == 'page1') { require_once('path/to/file'); }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either make the css links absolute (starts with a `/test/`) or add a base for all your relative links by adding this to your page header:

```
<base href="/test/">
```

(the base URI may need to be adjusted, but it looks like you want it to be `/test/`)

The reason this is happening is because the browser will guess what the URI-base is depending on the URL that's loaded. When you put `http://127.0.0.1/test/` in the browser, the browser assumes the URI base is `/test/` and all relative links will have that appended to the front. But when you put `http://127.0.0.1/test/pages/edit` in your browser, it assumes the base is `/test/pages/` and thus your relative links get the wrong base appended to the front.

Comment: Yeah this was my problem. Fixed now! Thx :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that u did not give the proper path to the css. Always try to call style/script from base url as below:
Hope this helps.

```
   <?php 
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1')
   define("SITEROOT","http://localhost/test/"); // base to your web directory ie,www or htdocs
    ?>
    //call style in this manner
    <link href="<?php echo SITEROOT; ?>Sourcefiles/cache/css/test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```